# Intel Graphics Driver for Intel GMA 3650 on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics, intel

I just obtained a small computer from ASUS with Ubuntu pre-installed. The scrolling, video, and animations are sluggish and choppy, though. The *Details* from *All Settings* states that the driver in use is "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)". However, the *Additional Drivers* claims that the driver in use is "drm driver for the Intel GMA500". I think that the computer is using the wrong driver, which could account for the choppiness in the scrolling and video. How can I correct this?

Computer Specs: 2GB RAM, 4x1.86GHz Intel Atom Processor, Intel GMA 3650 GPU

Comment: Not sure that there exist proprietary drivers for Intel cards. The open source drivers are always great. Have you tried using a different DE, to be more ressource friendly?

Comment: GMA3650 is one of the GPUs, for which Intel chose to provide no decent driver support, either closed or open. It all started in 2008 with the GMA500 GPU, and has been going from bad to worse ever since. The "drm driver for the Intel GMA500" is indeed the correct and open driver, but it is neither always not great, in fact, it's pretty horrible feature wise.

Answer (score 0):

Clean install Ubuntu 13.10 32 bits, you will find your graphics card working much better and a performance boost, hope it helps you out on your doubt.

PS: your graphics wasn´t very well supported on the version you have.